Taking derivatives with multiple inputs in JAX
I am trying to take first and second derivatives of functions in JAX however, my ways of doing that give me the wrong number or zeros. I have an array with two columns for each variable and two rows for each input
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

rng = rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(1234)
array = jax.random.normal(rng, (2,2))

Two test functions
def F1(arr):
    return 1/arr

def F2(arr):
    return jnp.array([arr[0]**2 + arr[1]**3])

and two methods of taking first and second derivatives, one using jax.grad()
def dF_m1(arr, F):
    return jax.grad(lambda arr: F(arr)[0])(arr)

def ddF_m1(arr, F, dF):
    return jax.grad(lambda arr: dF(arr, F)[0])(arr)

and another using jax.jacobian()
def dF_m2(arr, F):
    jac = jax.jacobian(lambda arr: F(arr))(arr)
    return jnp.diag(jac)

def ddF_m2(arr, F, dF):
    hess = jax.jacobian(lambda arr: dF(arr, F))(arr)
    return jnp.diag(hess)

Computing the first and second derivative (and error) of each function using both methods gives the following
exact_dF1  = (-1/array**2)
exact_ddF1 = (2/array**3)

print("Function 1 using all grad()")
dF1_m1 = jax.vmap(dF_m1, in_axes=(0,None))(array, F1)
ddF1_m1 = jax.vmap(ddF_m1, in_axes=(0,None,None))(array, F1, dF_m1)
print(dF1_m1  - exact_dF1,"\n")
print(ddF1_m1 - exact_ddF1,"\n")

print("Function 1 using all jacobian()")
dF1_m2 = jax.vmap(dF_m2, in_axes=(0,None))(array, F1)
ddF1_m2 = jax.vmap(ddF_m2, in_axes=(0,None,None))(array, F1, dF_m2)
print(dF1_m2  - exact_dF1,"\n")
print(ddF1_m2 - exact_ddF1,"\n")

Output
Function 1 using all grad()
[[ 0.         48.43877   ]
 [ 0.          0.62903005]] 

[[  0.        674.248    ]
 [  0.          0.9977852]] 

Function 1 using all jacobian()
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]] 

[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]] 

and
exact_dF2  = jnp.hstack( (2*array[:, 0:1], 3*array[:, 1:2]**2))
exact_ddF2 = jnp.hstack( (2 + 0*array[:, 0:1], 6*array[:, 1:2]))

print("Function 2 using all grad()")
dF2_m1 = jax.vmap(dF_m1, in_axes=(0,None))(array, F2)
ddF2_m1 = jax.vmap(ddF_m1, in_axes=(0,None,None))(array, F2, dF_m1)
print(dF2_m1  - exact_dF2,"\n")
print(ddF2_m1 - exact_ddF2,"\n")

print("Function 2 using all jacobian()")
dF2_m2 = jax.vmap(dF_m2, in_axes=(0,None))(array, F2)
ddF2_m2 = jax.vmap(ddF_m2, in_axes=(0,None,None))(array, F2, dF_m2)
print(dF2_m2  - exact_dF2,"\n")
print(ddF2_m2 - exact_ddF2,"\n")

Output
Function 2 using all grad()
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]] 

[[0.         0.86209416]
 [0.         7.5651155 ]] 

Function 2 using all jacobian()
[[ 0.         -0.10149619]
 [ 0.         -6.925739  ]] 

[[0.        2.8620942]
 [0.        9.565115 ]] 

I would prefer only to use jax.grad() for something like F1 but it seems right now that only jax.jacobian is working. The whole reason for this is that I need to calculate higher-order derivatives of a neural network with respect to its inputs. Thank you for any help.

The post was getting crowded but oddly enough if you use jax.grad() then jax.jacobian() for F1 all derivatives are correct, dF2_m1 = jax.vmap(dF_m1, in_axes=(0,None))(array, F2) ddF2_m12 = jax.vmap(ddF_m2, in_axes=(0,None,None))(array, F2, dF_m1) print(dF2_m1  - exact_dF2,"\n") print(ddF2_m12 - exact_ddF2,"\n"). But I am looking to only use jax.grad() to obtain higher-order derivatives.

Assuming exact_* is what you're attempting to compute, you're going about it in the wrong way. Your indexing within the differentiated functions (i.e. ...[0]) is removing some of the elements that you're trying to compute.
What exact_dF1 and exact_ddF1 are computing is element-wise first and second derivatives for 2D inputs. You can compute this using either grad or jacobian by applying vmap twice (once for each input dimension). For example:
exact_dF1  = (-1/array**2)
grad_dF1 = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(jax.grad(F1)))(array)
jac_dF1 = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(jax.jacobian(F1)))(array)
print(jnp.allclose(exact_dF1, grad_dF1))  # True
print(jnp.allclose(exact_dF1, jac_dF1))  # True

exact_ddF1 = (2/array**3)
grad_ddF1 = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(jax.grad(jax.grad(F1))))(array)
jac_ddF1 = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(jax.jacobian(jax.jacobian(F1))))(array)
print(jnp.allclose(exact_ddF1, grad_ddF1))  # True
print(jnp.allclose(exact_ddF1, jac_ddF1))  # True

What exact_dF2 and exact_ddF2 are computing is a row-wise jacobian and hessian of a 2D->1D mapping. By its nature, this is difficult to compute using jax.grad, which is meant for functions with scalar output, but you can compute it using the jacobian this way:
exact_dF2  = jnp.hstack( (2*array[:, 0:1], 3*array[:, 1:2]**2))
exact_ddF2 = jnp.hstack( (2 + 0*array[:, 0:1], 6*array[:, 1:2]))

jac_dF2 = jax.vmap(jax.jacobian(lambda a: F2(a)[0]))(array)
jac_ddF2_full = jax.vmap(jax.jacobian(jax.jacobian(lambda a: F2(a)[0])))(array)
jac_ddF2 = jax.vmap(jnp.diagonal)(jac_ddF2_full)
print(jnp.allclose(exact_dF2, jac_dF2))  # True
print(jnp.allclose(exact_ddF2, jac_ddF2))  # True

